# Change item value in list when it is moved to maintain sorting order

Tags: sql-server, sorting

My business use case is I have list of items and will store order of items when adding items into the list.

If I want to move an item to 2nd place then I need to update total items order to maintain list in sorted order.

To avoid this I need to create big gaps for each item order value.I have done this by giving the first item order value 2 billion and for second item I am halving that and assign 1billion and so on.

If any item is moved from one position to another position then I am getting average of above and below position values of new position and assigning that new order to current item and inserting that at new position.So we don't need to change other items order values.

But when adding items to list by using halving logic I can only insert 31 items with different orders after that other inserted orders are assigned to 0.I need every item to have different order so that I can get values in sorted order.
If you know Team Foundation server you can look at how the backlog priority works.

Do we have any algorithm to achieve this type of mechanism?Let me know if you have any solution.If my question is unclear look at 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/05/14/behind-the-scenes-the-backlog-priority-or-stack-rank-field.aspx 
In that link they have explained how backlog priority works.
But I want more information and logic for my business.

Comment: please format your question to get it more readable atm its jst a long wall of text that is absolutely unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use a time to also determine the order, so that the later something was moved the lower it's value in the order?

e.g. If you moved an item to between 3 and 4, you would give the moved item a value of 4, but because the time it moved was later than the original "4" you can display a different order.

```
Order   Value   "Timestamp"  Displayed order
01      AAAA    12:00        1
02      BBBB    12:00        2
03      CCCC    12:00        3
04      DDDD    12:00        4
05      EEEE    12:00        5
```

Then let's say you move "EEEE" to between 3 and 4.
Take the higher of the two bounds, and assign it, but use the new updated timestamp to order them.

```
Order   Value   "Timestamp"  Displayed order
01      AAAA    12:00        1
02      BBBB    12:00        2
03      CCCC    12:00        3
04      EEEE    12:30        4
04      DDDD    12:00        5
```

So it is sorted on order ascending then by timestamp descending.
This way you only have to update the moved item.
I guess you could run something overnight which will renumber the orders properly if required.